# how to use named routes in view where named routes have wildcard

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've a group routes like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{username}'],function()
{
    Route::get('', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);

    Route::get('settings', ['as' => 'settings', 'uses' => 'AdminController@settings']);
});
```

In my view i used named routes for link reference like this

```
<li><a href="{{ route( 'settings' ) }}"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
```

but it's rendering as

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/%7Busername%7D/settings"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
```

the username is printing literally but not the actual value. What i really want is this

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/admin/john/settings"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
```

How to do this?

Comment: Just provide username as second parameter and you are good to go, check answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try following...

```
<li><a href="{{ route( 'settings', Auth::user()->username ) }}"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
```

You would have to pass current username as second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass route parameters when generating an URL. Like:

```
{{ route('settings', ['john']) }}
```

Obviously you would rather do something like:

```
{{ route('settings', [$user->name]) }}
```

Since you only have one parameter you don't even have to pass it as array:

```
{{ route('settings', $user->name) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

And thus the address looks better you can use [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtolower.php) if you have a username with a capital letter.

```
<li><a href="{{ route( 'settings', strtolower(Auth::user()->username) ) }}"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
```

**Caution**

`Auth::user()` is for the current user. If no one is logged in you get an error!
So you can do a check.

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <li><a href="{{ route( 'settings', strtolower(Auth::user()->username) ) }}"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is passing the wild card to view via controllers and use it in route as second parameter

first pass the wildcard in controller

```
public function index($username)
{
    return view('admin.dashboard', compact('username'));
}
```

and in view pass the variable in routes as second parameter

```
<li><a href="{{ route( 'settings', $username) }}"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
```